# The link on the main page banner to meta is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

It points to meta.mathoverflow.com, rather than meta.mathoverflow.net.

(and the scripts won't let me post this with just the line above)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That'd be the fifth time today I've made that mistake. Hopefully that's the last time. Fixed.